# getViewTreeObserver in for loop not working, why?

Tags: android

I want to receive the height of the layout every time, but now I get the height of the layout when the for loop is done. Does anyone know how to receive the height every time in a for loop?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < deelnemers.size(); i++) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View informatie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modeldeelnemer, null);

        TextView volgNummer = (TextView) informatie.findViewById(R.id.volgnummer);

        volgNummer.setText("Nummer: " + deelnemers.get(i).getVolgnummer() + " /");
        lLayout.addView(informatie);

        lLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                lLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                int height = lLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                int width = lLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general avoid to use the global layout listener that is bad practice. In the end you just want to know when the view is measured so hook that event. I wrote a small layout with a callback for observing OnMeasure calls. Check this layout: [MeasureCallbackLayout](https://gist.github.com/rekire/1acdb3c58ac9a8af432aac37e8950ced)

When you wrap that layout around your linear layout you can add the MeasureCallback and do what you want with the actual size:

```
measureCallbackLayout.addMeasureListener(new MeasureCallbackLayout.MeasureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMeasured() {
        int height = lLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = lLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
});
```